# para los que usan Vim y plugin NerdTree; ¿hay comando para pasar de un Buffer a la columna NerdTree?

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu, terminal, vim

Esto es para mejorar mi productividad; Uso `Nvim` y el plugin `NerdTree`, lo que sucede es que cuando abro `NerdTree` y busco el archivo que quiero, y lo abro, el cursor se pone en ese archivo(el nuebo buffer) y para volver a `NerdTree` tengo que poner `Ctr + n` para cerrar y volver a presionar `Ctr + n` para que aparesca `NerdTree` con el cursor dentro de la columna.

**¿hay algún comando para no tener que serrar y volver a abrir `NerdTree`?**, ósea pasar de un buffer a la columna NerdTree abierta directamente.
he buscado en varios foros y aun no he encontrado algo que me ayude.

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola cuando recien iniciaba tambien tenia el mismo problema pero encontre un plugin el cual permita navegar entre ventanas con atajos de teclado configurables, el plugin es:

https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator

Automaticamente puedes ir a NerdTree mediante Ctrl+h y te puedes mover presionando control y hjkl depende del lado de la ventana la verdad es muy intuitivo.

espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: gracias!!! ya lo probé y es genial para aumentar la productividad.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> para saltar entre NerdTree y el archivo que abriste, y cuando quieras abrir más de un archivo por NerdTree te recomiendo que en lugar de usar <kbd>w</kbd>Enter presiones la tecla <kbd>t</kbd> así se abrirá el archivo en un nueva ventana, y para saltar entre archivos abiertos usa `gt` o `gT`.

Answer (score 1):

[La respuesta de @Wiskani](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/532681) es la correcta, pero me gustaría aportar algunas cosillas.

Si estando en `NerdTree` se pulsa **`?`**, abre la ayuda. Ahí se encontrarán algunas cosas interesantes. Resumo qué se puede hacer para que no se tenga que buscarlas.

- `?` : Abre la ayuda
- `t` : Abre el archivo en una nueva ventana, como bien dice el compañero @Wiskani.
- `s` : Abre el archivo en una ventana vertical (pantalla partida, comando `vsplit`).
- `i` : Abre el archivo en una ventana horizontal (pantalla partida, comando `split`)
- `I` : Muestra los ficheros ocultos en NerdTree.
- `T` : lo abre en una nueva pestaña en segundo plano.

Mi consejo es que si uno se pierde, se abra la ayuda con **`?`**, está todo muy bien explicado en forma de lista.